# Android : activity killed by Android as activity can't gain focus

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, android-windowmanager

I have a problem that happens randomly. This problem induces a restart of my app but I don't see any crash in LogCat (no FATAL EXCEPTION).

Here are the steps to produce this bug:

1. Launch the app (Activity A launched)
2. Launch Activity B
3. Launch Activity C
4. Click back to go back to B (the problem can occur randomly here)
5. Click back to go back to A (the problem can also occur randomly here)

Here are the 'errors' I see in LogCat:

```
InputDispatcher: Waiting to send key to Window{7a53648 u0 com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.ActivityB} because there are unprocessed events that may cause focus to change

V/WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{7a53648 u0 com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.ActivityB} to null displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:560 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:6237 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.setFocusedApp:6602 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.setResumedActivityUncheckLocked:6642
```

I think that it is these errors that induce a restart of my app (without any fatal crash in LogCat or fatal error message displayed to the user). I don't think that I have any process pending in the activity closed by a click on the back button (I see in LogCat that I go through onPause and onStop).

Anybody knows what could induce this issue ? How to find the origin of the problem and solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that the app crashes and restarts the log, that's why you don't see the fatal crash. Can you check in the top-right corner of LogCat, if "No Filter" is selected? If it isn't, please select it and try to reproduce the crash again, and check the LogCat.

Comment: Please share your code. Otherwise there is no way to find solution of your problem.

Comment: @BanMarkovic Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it is not the case. I see everything before the 'crash' (since the first launch of the app) in the LogCat.

Comment: @Regis_AG please share the functional codes which launches the activities and terminates the activities.